# Unable to generate a WAR file for a spring MVC application using intelliJ 13

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am unable to define a war artifact using Maven. In intelliJ, you can define artifacts in the deployment tab (see image). When I try to define the war artifact,

[image: Run/debug config]

I get this error message `TomEE required to support EAR/EJB deployment` and the application does not create a war

[image: error message]

could use some advice, thanks.

### edit: added plugin listing

[image: Tomcat and TomEE Integration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `artifactID` did not match what I have in the image `examqa` in the `pom.xml` file. Once this change was made, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the 'Tomcat and TomEE integration' plugin.